# AssertionError: Invalid CUDA '--device 0' requested, use '--device cpu' or pass valid CUDA device(s) python train_dual.py in GoogleColabratory

Tags: google-colaboratory, nvidia, yolo

I am using Google Collab to try to reconstruct yolo9 so that I can then train it for custom objects.* https://deasadiqbal.medium.com/yolov9-object-detection-on-custom-dataset-computer-vision-project-357bac70daeb*

When I entered `!python train_dual.py --workers 8 --batch 4  --img 640 --epochs 50 --data /content/yolov9/data.yaml --weights /content/yolov9-e.pt --device 0 --cfg /content/yolov9/models/detect/yolov9.yaml --hyp /content/yolov9/data/hyps/hyp.scratch-high.yaml`

I got the following error message:

````
2024-03-13 21:16:22.000080: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:607] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
2024-03-13 21:16:22.001565: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1515] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2024-03-13 21:16:23.188892: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
train_dual: weights=/content/yolov9-e.pt, cfg=/content/yolov9/models/detect/yolov9.yaml, data=/content/yolov9/data.yaml, hyp=/content/yolov9/data/hyps/hyp.scratch-high.yaml, epochs=50, batch_size=4, imgsz=640, rect=False, resume=False, nosave=False, noval=False, noautoanchor=False, noplots=False, evolve=None, bucket=, cache=None, image_weights=False, device=0, multi_scale=False, single_cls=False, optimizer=SGD, sync_bn=False, workers=8, project=runs/train, name=exp, exist_ok=False, quad=False, cos_lr=False, flat_cos_lr=False, fixed_lr=False, label_smoothing=0.0, patience=100, freeze=[0], save_period=-1, seed=0, local_rank=-1, min_items=0, close_mosaic=0, entity=None, upload_dataset=False, bbox_interval=-1, artifact_alias=latest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/yolov9/train_dual.py", line 644, in <module>
    main(opt)
  File "/content/yolov9/train_dual.py", line 524, in main
    device = select_device(opt.device, batch_size=opt.batch_size)
  File "/content/yolov9/utils/torch_utils.py", line 114, in select_device
    assert torch.cuda.is_available() and torch.cuda.device_count() >= len(device.replace(',', '')), \
AssertionError: Invalid CUDA '--device 0' requested, use '--device cpu' or pass valid CUDA device(s)```

I am new at this and appreciate your assistance and may need more as I go along.
````

Answer (score 0):

You should join [the YOLO discord server](https://discord.gg/zSq8rtW).  In the #general channel, the topic of YOLOv9 has been discussed recently by many users.  The conclusion from everyone was the same:  YOLOv9 is not ready for general use.  Not just build problems, but it doesn't work well with custom datasets.

If what you want to use is *specifically* YOLOv9, then what I'm writing to you right now is not an answer to your post.  Sorry!

If instead what you really want is to use YOLO on colab, then I have a different proposal to mention.  Take a look at the #darknet-and-google-colab channel on the discord server I linked to above.  There are several notebooks pinned to the channel that explains step-by-step how to use Darknet/YOLO on google colab.  For example:  [image: output from google colab notebook]

Comment: I appreciate it! I am trying to do fish id and count to assist conservation efforts in Florida. Any advice is appreciated! Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Fish ID and tracking definitely can be done.  See here for a tracking example I did a little while ago:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2biQpVRFhbk

Comment: Sorry been diving and shooting steady here in the keys! Thanks, Ste'phane! Appreciate your help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to already provided answers I have an additional clue:

You are using Colab and there are different GPUs and setups available.
**Some Colab setups does not have a GPU!**

As the CUDA-Error suggests you might want to use the `cpu` (by using `device="cpu"` instead of `device=0` or suggested CLI arguments) or activate GPU support.
To activate GPUs in Google Colab navigate to `Edit -> Notebook Settings` and select a GPU from the Hardware Accelerator menu (as clearly described in this [Google "TensorFlow with GPU" Guideline](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/gpu.ipynb), which applies to your case).